# Search Bar Scope Dropdown not visible on My Sites?

Tags: search, my-site, search-results, search-scope

I customized My Sites to look like regular SharePoint 2010 sites so that when the ribbon is not active the logo/header of a company is visible AND I added the placeholder for the search barin that area as well.

Now the search bar shows up without any problem but I can't seem to make the Scope Dropdown appear next to it...under Search Setting in Site Settings I changed the dropdown to 'Show Scope Dropdown' and link to my search center site which is in another site collection. From what I know this sould be enough to make the scope dropdown be visible but it is not working.

Any ideas why its not visible? I need to either make the scope dropdown visible or make the default search scope 'All Sites' rather than 'This Site'.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe that search scope/box control is available within the MySites MasterPage.  If you go to a personal site with the standard MasterPage and CSS applied, that site property is ignored.

Comment: Well I am using a custome master page and CSS and have added the search bar control onto the site. I removed the people search control that is OOTB and added the same on as on regular sites (copy/paste from v4.master) any idea how I can get the scope dropdown into the masterpage?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found the way of adding Search Scope drop down to My Sites.

If you look to the Master page, you will see that search box is situated in DelegateControl. I identified that the problem may be connected with DelegateControl in Master page.  As I did my research regarding that subject, I found out that by default search scope box is hidden in master page through DelegateControl, so you need to create a custom delegate control which will show search scope.

Here are the steps:

- Create a new project and add new feature there.
- Add a new Empty Element in your project and customize it by adding a control and its properties. Here is a great resource on how to do it: http://www.fivenumber.com/understanding-sharepoint-delegate-control/

After deploying your project, you will be able to see search scope drop down. Hope this will help.

Here I the resource: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/d7463468-fa58-40d6-b23c-31326d9c17be/showing-search-scope-on-mysites-default-page?forum=sharepointsearchlegacy